# Does using Veux store impact application's performance?

Tags: vue.js, vuex-modules

Is using Vuex over local data in the component adds performance overhead? Does it make the application slow?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think you shouldn't worry about that. Vuex was created to organice your code and most of applications use it because passing data between components using props and event could be difficult in larger apps. So, if your application has some kind of complexity related to passing data between components, you should use Vuex